# On a hotspot hprof, where do I find the captured values of a lambda?

Tags: java, lambda, heap-dump, yourkit

I'm investigating a heap dump taken by a Hotspot-1.8 JVM. The dump is in hprof format and contains thousands of lambda instances.

They're all created from functions like this:

```
public class Ref<T> {
  private T obj;

  void set(final T value) {
    obj = value;
    singletonMgr.register(() -> Ref.close(value));
  }

  private static <T> void close(T obj) { /* stuff */ }
}
```

Works and the lambda shows up in the list `singletonMgr` manages. But it's empty apart from the `<class>` reference each object gets. I would have expected a reference to `value` in there?

What am I missing and how can I evaluate each Lambda's `value`?

Comment: I just tried it and had no problems seeing the captured value (fields are typically named `arg$1`, etc.). —I used JVisualVM, though.